# Регулярное выражение - валидация кириллицы (Laravel FormRequest)

Tags: регулярные-выражения, axios, laravel-5.7

Делаю запрос от клиента (Vue) к API:

```
storeUser() {
        let that = this
        axios.post(//url, {
          name: that.user.name,
        })
      }
```

`FormRequest`:

```
//StoreUser class
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => [
                'required',
                'string',
                'max:255',
                'regex:/^[\w\- \p{Cyrillic}]*$/'
            ]
        ];
    }
```

Метод контроллера:

```
public function store(StoreUser $request)
{
    return response($request); //заглушка
}
```

При попытке отправить запрос с `Payload` вида `{"name":"тест"}` получаю ошибку валидации на этапе `regex`. В чем модет быть проблема?

В онлайн-валидаторе все ок.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также пробовал `'regex:/^[\w\- а-я]*$/'`, не помогло.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решено `'regex:/^[\w\- \p{Cyrillic}]*$/u'` при помощи добавления `u` (unicode) модификатора.

Comment: Вы так делаете валидацию json?

Comment: @Let'ssayPie мне нужно было сделать валидацию для слов, состоящих из кириллицы/латиницы, цифр, также "-" и "_". А в чем плох такой подход?

Comment: думаю можно такой вариант: `/^[\-\w ]+$/ui`

Comment: но в `\w` входят еще цифры, поэтому, я думаю, что лучше всего под ваши требования подойдет: `/^[\-\p{L}_ ]+$/ui`

Comment: `/^[\-\p{L}_ ]+$/ui` не пропустит, к примеру "тест qwe 123" (как я говорил выше, цифры тоже присутствуют в словосочетаниях).

Comment: Все, увидел, тогда используйте первый вариант.